# Manipulando valores de array em PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou armazenando um array em uma session, mas não estou conseguindo manipulá-lo. Como eu faço para somar todos os valores do array?

eu tentei desta forma:

```
$item = $_SESSION['item'];
$total = 0;
foreach($item as $x) {
    $total += $x;
}
echo $total;
exit();
```

porém, o retorno é:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz_Acaro\final.php on line 70
0
```

Comment: Pode fazer `var_dump($item)` na segunda linha e postar o resultado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss 
23string(2) "23"

Comment: Então há uma *string* na sua sessão, não um *array*. Como você definiu a sessão?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é um passo a passo. 

na primeira parte, o usuário tem checkboxes para marcar, e envia os valores via post. mandando via post, var_dump($item) retorna o array, não string. então, provavelmente o erro está da etapa 2 para a etapa 3 (são 3 etapas)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: Então coloque na pergunta o seu código completo, principalmente o código referente às etapas 2 e 3, seja lá o que isso significa.

Comment: consegui. Obrigado pela ajuda :D

Comment: Como conseguiu? Você estava definindo a sessão de forma errada? Qual era o erro?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na etapa 2 eu estava transformando o array em string na hora de enviar para a etapa 3

Comment: Então coloque o código completo na pergunta e depois responda como resolveu o problema. Ao meu ver, o erro estava na definição da sessão, não na leitura, então as respostas dadas, mesmo corretas, não resolveriam o problema descrito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse erro significa que você esta tentando iterar em um elemento que não é um array.

Primeiro voce precisa saber/garantir que o valir do item é um array

```
$item = $_SESSION['item'];
$total = 0;

if(is_array($item)){
    foreach($item as $x) {
        $total += $x;
    }
    echo $total;
}else{
    echo 'Ops! Esse item nao é um array';
}
exit();
```

Answer (score 2):

O erro `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` Acontece quando você passa no `foreach` um valor não iterável.

Sendo assim, você deveria ter uma verificação se realmente o valor `$_SESSION['item']` pode ser iterado:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['item']) && is_array($_SESSION['item']) {

     // Resto do seu código aqui
}
```

Eu optei por usar `isset`, porque se você usar `is_array` diretamente, será emitido um `E_NOTICE`, caso o índice `'item'` da `array` não exista.

Comment: E por quê não [`is_iterable`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-iterable.php)? :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não sabia que existia isso no PHP :D. Eu só uso PHP 5.6